# Is it thread safe to call BackgroundJob.Enqueue one the same method/service in a loop?

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-core, thread-safety, hangfire

I have an API that receives a large list of items that should be treated and inserted/updated in a database. the api serves a console app that runs as cron job.
The list is within 10s of thousands of items, and the database has millions of rows. the operation is the update of some time series data.
In the SQL queries I'm using "where In @someIds" (against SQL server), this is one reason why I am trying to do this in batches, the other one is to use multithreading to take advantage of all the cores of the cpu.
I'm trying to leverage Hangfire to parallelize the work doing something like this.

```
public async Task DoWork(List<Item> list)
{
    var listOfLists = GetBatchedList(list);

    foreach (var singlelist in listOfLists)
    {
       BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => _heavyWorkService.DoHeavyWork(singlelist));
    }
}
```

```
public class HeavyWorkService : IHeavyWorkService
{
   private readonly IResultService _resultService;

   public HeavyWorkService(IResultService resultService)
   {
      _resultService = resultService; 
   }

   public async Task DoHeavyWork(List<Item> list)
   {
       await _resultsService.CalculateAndMerge(list);
   }
}
```

```
public class ResultService : IResultService
{
   private readonly IAppRespository _repository;

   public ResultService(IAppRespository repository)
   {
      _repository = repository; 
   }

   public async Task CalculateAndMerge(List<Item> list)
   {
       var result = new List<Result>();
       var typeAData = await _repository.GetTypeAData(list);
       var typeBData = await _repository.GetTypeBData(list);

       foreach(var item in list)
       {
          // typeA and typeB static data processing
          result.Add(new Result( , , ));
       }
    
       await _repository.DoMerge(result);
   }
}
```

```
public class AppRespository : IAppRespository
{
   private readonly IConnectionProvider _connectionProvider;

   public AppRespository(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
   {
      _connectionProvider = connectionProvider;
   }

   public async Task<TypeA> GetTypeAData(List<Item> list)
   {
      var query = $@"select * from TypeATable 
                     join.....where id in @ids";

      using var connection = _connectionProvider.GetConnection();

      return await connection.QueryAsync<Security>(query, new list.Select(x=> x.Id)});
   
   public async Task DoMerge(List<Result> result)
   {
      var createTempTableSql = $@"creat table #TempSource ...";
      var mergeQuery = $@"merge into dbo.TypeC...";
      // Use transaction to create temp table,bulk insert in temp table and merge
   }
}
```

Is this thread safe? if not how can I make it so?

note 1: all the services/repositories are injected as a transient service

Comment: There is not enough code here to determine if this is thread-safe or not. You are using `List<>` which is not thread-safe, but it might be being used safely. You are clearly expecting `_heavyWorkService.DoHeavyWork(singlelist)` to have some sort of side-effect, so that's potentially not thread-safe. If you want this to be thread-safe then use immutable types and don't have any methods produce any side-effects.

Comment: I'm mostly assuming that Hangfire is doing the heavy lifting and creating different processes for each call in the loop

Comment: You're not giving us enough to go on. Stop assuming things and give us a [mcve] so we can see the whole code working.

Comment: I have added more code and context, hopefully it's going to give you a better idea @Enigmativity

Comment: Please read [mcve] and let me know if you think the code you've posted meets that requirement.

Comment: @Enigmativity If you mean I need to post all the code, Stackoverlow form itself is telling this is too much code. If you mean something else, just be clear about it because I think there is enough information to at least start a conversation, or maybe just don't answer and waste both of our time.

Comment: "Minimal" is also a key word. Minimal, but necessary to reproduce the issue.